# affect only elements within parent on hover

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs which contain the same elements, I want the effect to happen only within the div where the hover is taking place.

I have this html:

```
<div class="item mit">
                    <div class="link"></div>

                    <div class="hidden">
                        <h2>mitagessen</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dictum est nec elit ornare molestie.</p>
                        <img src="img/food-pic.jpg">
                    </div> <!-- end .hidden -->

                    <div class="image"><img src="img/food-pic.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="image-text">
                        <p>Tagesmenü</p>
                        <h2>mittagessen</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the following jquery which works, but it hides all instances of `.image` and `.image-text`, not just the ones within the div which is being hovered.

```
$('div.link').mouseenter(function() {
            // $(this).hide();
            $('div.image').hide();
            $('div.image-text').hide();
            $('.hidden').show();
        });

        $('div.hidden').mouseleave(function() {
            // $('div.link').show();
            $('div.image').show();
            $('div.image-text').show();
            $('.hidden').hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the `.item` element to which the target element belongs to then target the elements in that.

```
$('div.link').mouseenter(function () {
    // $(this).hide();
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
    $item.find('div.image').hide();
    $item.find('div.image-text').hide();
    $item.find('.hidden').show();
});

$('div.hidden').mouseleave(function () {
    // $('div.link').show();
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
    $item.find('div.image').show();
    $item.find('div.image-text').show();
    $item.find('.hidden').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`

```
 // hide .image which is inside current .item
 $('div.image',$(this).closest('.item')).hide();
```